# Are there any Evangelion games out there in US or EU?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion, merchandise

I really like Evangelion's anime and movies, and love the universe, but don't speak Japanese. I've tried to find video games on the universe, but the closest I found which made reference to Evangelion was Phantasy Star Portable on PSP, which have a plug suit and Longinus spear as bonus equipment...

Are there any games placed in the Evangelion universe that have been at least officially translated into English?

To add a little to the question, video game websites list these games (for current platforms):

- PS3

  - Gekiatsu Pachige Damashii Max Evangelion (JAP only)
- DS

  - CR Neon Genesis Evangelion : Angels Return (JAP)
  - Puchi Eva : Evangelion Game (JAP)
- PSP

  - Evangelion : Jo (JAP)
  - Neon Genesis Evangelion : Battle Orchestra Portable (JAP)
  - Neon Genesis Evangelion : Girlfriend of Steel Special Version (JAP)
  - Neon Genesis Evangelion : Shinjitsu no Tsubasa (JAP/cancelled?)
  - Neon Genesis Evangelion : Tamashii no Kiseki (JAP)
  - Rebuild of Evangelion Sound Impact (PlayStation Store) (JAP/cancelled?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of those games have any official translation or has been localized to English. There is a fan-translated version of the first Girlfriend of Steel that was ported to Flash. I don't know how accurate it is or where you'd go to find it these days.

Along with the list that you have, there's a couple of more [listed in this wiki Category](https://wiki.evageeks.org/Category%3aVideo_Games), which isn't complete by a long shot.

Outside of official translations, you can look through faqs at places like [Game Faqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/psp/930008-neon-genesis-evangelion-tsukurareshi-sekai-another/faqs/45735) which includes translations of the UI and game text. It's not nearly as convenient but it's really all there is.

Comment: What a shame for non japanese fan. Thanks you.